# Kotlin get type as string

Tags: java, kotlin

I can't find how to get the type of a variable (or constant) as `String`, like `typeof(variable)`, with Kotlin language. How to accomplish this?

Comment: You should clarify what you want to do with the "type of a variable", if for instance checking "a is instance of b" then you don't want a string.  If for display, or some other use then maybe a string.

Comment: Quite simple: variable::class

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use one of the methods that best suits your needs:

```
val obj: Double = 5.0

System.out.println(obj.javaClass.name)                 // double
System.out.println(obj.javaClass.kotlin)               // class kotlin.Double
System.out.println(obj.javaClass.kotlin.qualifiedName) // kotlin.Double
```

You can fiddle with this [here](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/ols2tsupj16iium7j6fcsv6kou/nfedagar0hmtt4a947imqig2ls).

Comment: Yes, I think that `javaClass`, as stated in the other comments, is the answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the nullable types. For example if you had 
    `val obj = getInt();`
where `getInt()` returns a `Int?` type, then trying
    `obj.javaClass.name`
results in compilation error

Comment: If your property is nullable, then you of course have to run `obj?.javaClass?.name` which returns `null` for null values

Comment: In case you face a `kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36440329/5800527

Comment: It's worth pointing out that these names can get mangled by obfuscation (ProGuard and R8).

Answer (score 16):

There is a simpler way using `simpleName` property and avoiding *Kotlin* prefix.

```
val lis = listOf(1,2,3)
```

`lis` is from type `ArrayList`. So one can use

```
println(lis.javaClass.kotlin.simpleName)  // ArrayList
```

or, more elegantly:

```
println(lis::class.simpleName)  // ArrayList
```

Comment: This does not give the complete type.  In your instance it says, "ArrayList" instead of "ArrayList of Int" which is much more complete.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the '::class' keyword that gives the type of an instance. The property .simpleName return the string name of the returned class.

```
var variable = MyClass()

var nameOfClass = variable::class.simpleName

nameofClass >> "MyClass"
```

Comment: Write a few words about your answer. Explaining your answer makes it easier to OP to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

[Type Checks and Casts: 'is' and 'as'](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html)

```
if (obj is String) {
  print(obj.length)
}

if (obj !is String) { // same as !(obj is String)
  print("Not a String")
}
```

Comment: Same thing as the @michael answer

Comment: @michael answered in Java not Kotlin.  This answer from Rodrigo is for Kotlin,  The difference is that `instanceof` does not exist in Kotlin, but instead the [`is` and `!is` operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#is-and-is-operators)