# kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError: Kotlin reflection implementation is not found at runtime. Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar

Tags: kotlin

When I compile I got the above error. My gradle file as below : -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package.name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 6
        versionName "2.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4:$anko_version"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.1-2'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

And my project gradle as below

```
buildscript {
    ext.support_version = '23.2.1'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.1'
    ext.anko_version = '0.8.3'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Did I miss adding anything?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

From the error, I assume:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
```

in your `dependencies` in addition to the standard library.

Comment: Thanks! Found we need `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"` as per in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

Comment: Perhaps not obvious: (1) must be double quotes, not single, otherwise $kotlin_version won't expand,  (2) according to https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies , the :$kotlin_version can be omitted if it's >= 1.1.2.  But that seems to be broken for me (my $kotlin_version is 1.2.10 currently); the error message shows that it constructs a bogus url such as `https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect//kotlin-reflect-.jar`.  So, I am still using the recipe in this answer.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `implementation` is now the favored directive over `compile`:

`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"`

Comment: is there any proguard rule for this dependency?

Comment: I still get the error.. Even using the shadow jar plugin (and indeed I confirmed that `kotlin-reflect` is in the .jar

Comment: I added a very basic Kotest test and am not sure why I need this, but it works now.

Comment: `Could not get unknown property 'kotlin_version'`

Answer (score 8):

I resolved this by adding this in build.gradle

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.61"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was not having the same versions of kotlin I'm my modules and lib
so I had to force them to use the same version

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'org.jetbrains.kotlin') {
                details.useVersion versions.kotlin
            }
        }
    }}
```