# Kotlin & Gradle - Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I am working on a app using Kotlin language and Gradle Build in IntelliJ IDEA IDE. I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError: Kotlin reflection implementation is not found at runtime. Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath
    at kotlin.jvm.internal.ClassReference.error(ClassReference.kt:86)
    at kotlin.jvm.internal.ClassReference.getQualifiedName(ClassReference.kt:26)
    at WorkerKt.main(Worker.kt:62)
```

I have included the dependencies as mentioned in following answer [Add kotlin-reflect dependency in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36440329/6862286)

Even I have added the jar file in libs folder but still I am getting above error at runtime.

My Gradle file is as below:

```
group 'com.working.workerhelp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Is there something I need to configure for Gradle Build or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you re-import the modified `build.gradle` file in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 27):

add `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"` in `build.gradle(Module:app)`

remove `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"` from project level `build.gradle`

Comment: The above answer also applies to custom gradle build plugins, if some errors like `KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError` arise.

Comment: with the kotlin gradle DSL, assuming you have `plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "$kotlin_version"
}` then you can say `dependencies { compile(kotlin("reflect")) }`